# Configuring two routers, lan to lan or lan to wan?

Tags: networking, router, lan, wan

I've recently got a fiber connection installed so now I have 2 routers, the new `alcatel` (192.168.1.254) optical fiber one and my old expensive `tp-link` (192.168.1.1) router. I want the `tp-link` router to be the master and use the alcatel one only to connect to fiber.

So I tried the following:

- I connected both routers together via an ethernet cable on regular
  ethernet ports, disabled DHCP on `alcatel` and kept it on  `tp-link`.
- Configured the DHCP `gateway` and `dns` on `tp-link` to point to 
  `alcatel` (192.168.1.254)

Now all devices connect to the `tp-link` and get internet from the `alcatel` router, all looks good. But my main `tp-link` router functionalities like bandwidth control have no effect now.

What would be the proper way to hook this up, keeping in mind I want to maintain all the good functionalities that came with my `tp-link` router and I want all devices to see other? Maybe I should do a lan to wan setup, but that looks like a lot of configuration?

By the way, my main desktop is connected to the `alcatel` router directly, getting it's ip info from `tp-link` however. I prefer to keep my main desktop connected directly to the router that have internet (which is the `alcatel`).

edit: [pics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95npR.jpg) of alcatel and connections to it

Comment: Does your provider alcatel router include the media converter, or is that seperate?  (If its seperate, you can ditch the alcatel router altogether).

Comment: If you are keeping both, you would typically connect the LAN of the Fibre router to the WAN of the TPLink router, but you will need to modify the LAN interface on one device - they can't both be in 192.168.x.x (where x.x overlap as is the case here [ i've simplified my answer to ignore talking about netmasks etc).  I'd suggest renumbering one onto 10.x.x.x)

Comment: @davidgo regarding your first question, see my edit, hope it makes it clearer

Comment: It would be better to use bridge mode on the Alcatel device. Look up the model and "bridge mode" and you'll probably find something. That should turn the Alcatel into a glorified modem, and leave all the routing to the TP-Link. Then you plug in from LAN  of Alcatel to WAN of TP-Link.

Comment: @MagnaVis For some reason some options in the alcatel router are disabled (greyed out), for example port settings, see http://i.imgur.com/FFRp8uy.png Also I remember the guy that installed it told me that I can't set it to bridge mode or something of the likes.. any ideas? (Btw Device name: G-240W-A and Vendor is Alcatel_Lucent, taken from the alcatel info page.

Comment: Contact their support or use Google-Fu. Many of those routers have logins and passwords that are related to the serial or MAC address. It's likely that you'll be able to get yourself some access to make those changes. I had to do something similar with my FiOS box from Verizon. I think the login was the last 6 of the MAC. SUPER secure. ;)

Comment: Are you suggesting there is another user that have full-access? I'm currently using the user on the sticker on the back of the router, user is `userAdmin`. Also why would they disable such options? edit: interesting, found this in the manual: The default username and password are printed on the ONT. The default user
name is userAdmin. The default superuser name is AdminGPON. Contact
Alcatel-Lucent for the superuser password. edit2: found the password for AdminGPON and all options are not greyed out now.. why would they disable bridging from regular admins? :-|

Comment: Still going to configure all of this tomorrow so I wouldn't mind hearing your opinions on whats best, so far from what I gather here, either connect `alcatel` lan to `tp-link` wan (without bridging), or do it with bridging, personally i'm not sure what's the difference, excuse my ignorance in this matter.